# What number types are used in web3.py

Tags: web3.py

I am listening ethereum network via web3.py filters and saving some transactions to mongo. I am concerned about overflow issues, because I am receiving values in transactions in weis (10^18). Can python handle sunch big numbers correctly and can mongo handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 can handle arbitrarily large integers. No need to worry about overflow there.

You're more likely to get quality answers about MongoDB on a different forum (maybe StackOverflow?).